# How to segment depth image faster?

Tags: kinect, image-segmentation, point-cloud-library

I need to segment depth image that captured from 
a kinect device in realtime(30fps).

Currently I am using EuclideanClusterExtraction from PCL, it works but very slow(1fps).

Here is a paragraph in the PCL tutorial:

> “Unorganized” point clouds are characterized by non-existing point references between points from different point clouds due to varying size, resolution, density and/or point ordering. In case of “organized” point clouds often based on a single 2D depth/disparity images with fixed width and height, a differential analysis of the corresponding 2D depth data might be faster.

So I think there are faster method to segment depth image.

- The project doesn't use the RGB Camera, so I need a segmentation method that use only the depth image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCL provides segmentation algorithms optimised for organised point clouds.

For details see:

- The tutorial here describing them and showing how to use them:
  http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/icra2012/segmentation.pdf
- The example code in thePCL distribution (relatively late versions): `organized_segmentation_demo` and `openni_organized_multi_plane_segmentation`
- In the API, [OrganizedConnectedComponentSegmentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_organized_connected_component_segmentation.html) and [OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_organized_connected_component_segmentation.html). The latter builds on the former.